# JasperReport - Passagem de Objetos para coluna do relatório

Tags: java, classes, jasper-reports, ireport

Tenho que pegar o dado do seguinte campo :

```
venda.getVendacardinalidades().get(0).getUsuario().getPessoa().getNome()
```

E colocar este valor em uma coluna do relatório, como faço isso:

Estava tentando fazer assim:

```
<field name="nome" class="com.vendas.model.VendaCardinalidade"/>
...

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="187" height="20" forecolor="#666666" uuid="47de42ee-e4c9-4c89-9d64-03fb5ecb4fb6"/>
    <box rightPadding="2"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome.getVendacardinalidades().get(0).getUsuario().getPessoa().getNome()}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Mas dá errado, como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui através da lógica:

Fiz assim:

```
<field name="vendacardinalidades[0].usuario.pessoa.nome" class="java.lang.String"/>

...

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="187" height="20" forecolor="#666666" uuid="47de42ee-e4c9-4c89-9d64-03fb5ecb4fb6"/>
    <box rightPadding="2"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vendacardinalidades[0].usuario.pessoa.nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Certinho!!!